# Modifying the Default Django Login Page

Tags: html, css, django, django-authentication

I have a Django project that requires authentication, and the `django.contrib.auth` code has been working great so far. However, I'd like to edit the provided `login` page to say something like "MyProject administration" instead of "Django administration", and alter the colors in the CSS files a little bit. I'm having trouble finding where these files are located in the project.

Is there a way to edit the default files, or do I have to copy/rewrite all the functionality in my own files? I'd love to just tweak the defaults, if that's possible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! can directly modify the framework. the installation folder depends on what operating system you use and if you use virtualenv. you have to find this file in your pc and edit it: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html

if you use virtualenv can found it in this directory "virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin"

Comment: Django supports customizing admin views (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects). Please DO NOT edit django's login.html, that file may change if you upgrade your django version.